# Restore permissions in /private/etc

Tags: macos, terminal, permission

I was doing some work and accidentally changed permissions in `/private/etc` and some other folders in `private` using the Terminal.

From there I wasn’t able to `sudo` because `/private/etc/sudoers` had a wrong owner.

I tried to solve it by rebooting with <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and changing owner and group to `/private/etc/`, `/private/tmp/` and `/private/tftpboot/` recursively. When I try to `exit` to continue in *normal mode* I get a lot of `Process[XXX] crashed: opendirectoryd. Too many corpses being created.` messages, being XXX secuentials numbers starting from 170, do I make myself clear?.

Does anybody know what this error means? I’m running on a MacBook Pro mid 2012 with Mac OS High Sierra

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. :) I've edited out the second question about not being able to log in with your Apple ID. Hopefully getting a solution to your first question will resolve this as well, but if it doesn't then you can ask a separate question later. As for your current question, can you confirm what version of macOS you have installed? Also, can you clarify when you're getting the `Too many corpses being created` error? What else is on the screen?

Comment: Done @Monomeeth, check it out. And thanks for your time

Comment: Did you recursively (eg,  `chown -R /private/*`) change permissions in there? What command(s) did you run?

Comment: Permissions in /etc probably aren‘t as simple as you think, so changing them recursively might make things worse. Maybe it‘s easier to boot from the recovery partition and reinstall macOS.